# How to append my url in Post request using retrofit interface in android

Tags: retrofit2

I want to add or append my url in interface of retrofit. Code of interface is given below.

```
public interface PostInterface {
    @POST("api/v1/app/user/resetpassword/token")
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })

    Call<JsonObject> getResult(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

In the given url @POST("api/v1/wallet/user/resetpassword/**token**") i want to append token value.Which is value of a variable of an activity.

and my activity code is given below from where i am call the method.

```
try {
        JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
        params.addProperty("email", email);
        params.addProperty("signup_mode", "mobile");
        PostInterface apiService =TestApiClient.getClient(this).create(PostInterface.class);
        Call call = apiService.getResult(params);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood if this should be part of the path or part of the query parameters, so here's both ways.

**Part of the path**

The way to do this with retrofit is to make it a "variable" in the path and pass it as arguments to the function.

```
@POST("api/v1/app/user/resetpassword/{token}")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
Call<JsonObject> getResult(
       @Path("token") String token,
       @Body JsonObject body);
```

Notice the curly braces in `{token}` in the url. This tells retrofit that it should format an argument of your method into the url. To know which argument you use the annotation `Path` with the same name as the one being formatted. This results in urls like `api/v1/app/user/resetpassword/09df7seh98ghs` (09df7seh98ghs is my poor representation of a token).

*(this assumes your token is a String. Retrofit supports more than that.)*

**Part of the query parameters**

Similar to the way you do this with the `@Path` annotation you can use the `@Query` annotation:

```
@POST("api/v1/app/user/resetpassword/token")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
Call<JsonObject> getResult(
       @Query("token") String token,
       @Body JsonObject body);
```

The difference here is that retrofit will add the given token as a query parameter resulting in urls like `api/v1/app/user/resetpassword/token?token=...`

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got the answer of my question. Hope if any body is having such problem it can help in future.

Modification in interface:

```
 @POST
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
    Call<JsonObject> getResult(@Url String url, @Body JsonObject body);
```

Now inside your activity call back please do the following changes

```
try {
        JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
        params.addProperty("email", email);
        params.addProperty("signup_mode", "mobile");

   String url= Constants.BASE_URL+"api/v1/wallet/user/changepassword/"+userIdStr;

            PostInterface apiService = TestApiClient.getClient(this).create(PostInterface.class);
            Call call = apiService.getChangePassword(url,params);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
```

Its working fine.